# Accumulation points of a countable set in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let A be a countable subset of [0,1]. Denote the set of accumulation points of A by A'. Can the set of accumulation points of A' be nonempty (i.e. can we have that A'' is nonempty)?

Thanks for your help

Comment: *Hint:* What is the "simplest" countable subset of $[0,1]$?

Comment: yes, sorry, a very embarrassing question. but it has been answered so I cannot delete it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Take $A=\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$.